# Kendo UI grid 'change' event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo window and in the window, I have a kendo grid as a tab under the tab strip. I have the inline edit functionality in the grid. When I edit the grid and save, the change event gets fired and can get the dirty rows. It all works good. But when I switch to another tab and come back to the tab having the grid and do the inline edit, I can't get the dirty rows as the change event doesn't fire.

My change event is on the data source. My data source use $http.get method to fetch data and batch:true.

My grid configuration has below

```
height:140,
toolbar: [{...}],
excel : {},
selectable : "row",
editable : true,
columns : [{...}],
datasource : ds,
noRecords : ...
```

Any idea why the change event is not getting fired second time, when I switch back to tab having the grid.

Thank you very much. Appreciate your help.

**Update**

I tried with saveChanges event on the grid. Same behavior. On first click of the tab having the grid, all works good, but doesn't work when I switch to other tab return back to the tab having the grid.

Comment: are you able to provide a dojo or a fiddle or code example as it will be very difficult to diagnose your actual issue

Comment: Hi David! I wish i could able to provide dojo or fiddle. But unfortunately, the grid is big and it is placed under tab in tab strip and the tab strip opens up as a pop-up window. Sorry for not able to provide the dojo or fiddle.

Comment: https://dojo.telerik.com/EBORuPiq Here's a snippet, that does what you want. Is this like your scenario?

Comment: Hi Marco! Thank you for the answer. Yes! this is very close to my scenario. Only different I have is 1) under transport, I have only read & update. 2) I am not using pageSize. 3) And most importantly, I am using batch: true, which allows me to edit any cell on any row and I see that red tiny triangle on left hand up on the cell when I do any edit. 4) when I switch between tabs, andcome back to grid tab and do editing on the cell, this little red triangle appears, but the change event doesn't fire.

Comment: How are you loading the grid onto the tabstrip? Static html as in this example or from a partial?

Comment: Hi All, It works now. It's a mistake from our side. The data source and  change event on it was placed under if...else condition and it was not reachable when the grid is defined. Removed those unnecessary conditions and it works now. Thank you all for your help.